# Editing data shows validation errors for unique information

Tags: codeigniter, validation, unique

I'm using Codeigniter 3 validations for creating new users. Some of these validations consist of:

```
...
array(
    'field' => 'cpf_cnpj',
    'label' => 'CPF',
    'rules' => 'required|_validate_cpf|is_unique[usuario.cpf_cnpj]'
),
array(
    'field' => 'email',
    'label' => 'E-MAIL',
    'rules' => 'required|valid_email|is_unique[usuario.email]'
),
...
```

The issue is that when editing an existing User, if the e-mails provided during the creation is kept the same, the validation will fail. How to workaround this?

Comment: When editing an existing user you need to figure out a way to check if the email field has changed. If it has changed then you include the `is_unique`  rule, else exclude that rule.

Comment: But how? These rules are in a separated file.

Comment: Are they in `application/config/form_validation.php` ?

Comment: Yes, they are, they're in this file.

Comment: It is hard to help without seeing how you are using `form_validation`. For instance, there are multiple ways to setup and use `form_validation.php` not to mention all the other functions that the library offers. Edit your question and include enough code so what you are doing is understood.

Comment: I guess the only way how it is done. When I execute the `edit` method, it first checks `if ($this->form_validation->run([validations_name])) { ... } else { ... }`;